# Print out list number/ position

Tags: c#

I am trying to print out what number in the list a specific list value has. But I can't figure out how. The list is called passengers_list and the class is called Passenger. Does someone know how? I want to print out the position of the list value that fits in the argument below

```
int findAge1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int findAge2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        foreach (Passenger passenger in passengers_list)
        {
            if (passenger.Age <= findAge1 && passenger.Age >= findAge2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passagerare " + passenger + " är " + passenger.Age + "år gammal");
            }
        }
```

I may have solved it but it's a bit cheesed and I don't know if the teacher like this but I did this.

```
  int findAge1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int findAge2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int findPassenger = 0;
        foreach (Passenger passenger in passengers_list)
        {
            findPassenger ++;
            if (passenger.Age <= findAge1 && passenger.Age >= findAge2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passagerare " + findPassenger + " är " + passenger.Age + "år gammal");
            }
         
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the snippet you shared? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: I am just getting text like system class passenger and so on, but I want it to be a number, like passenegr 1 in passengers_list

Comment: That's how default `object.ToString()` method works... Asked multiple times... (`"" + instanceOfObject` == `"" + instanceOfObject.ToString()`)

Comment: Selvin I am trying to print out what position in the list that fits in the argument if you understand how i mean, so i want to like if passenger 6 in passengers_list it says 6 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what parameters your teacher gave you in this assignment but i believe the solution you have is just fine, but if you want it to look cleaner you have two options:

1. Use a normal for loop instead of the foreach:

```cs
int findAge1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int findAge2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int index = 1; index <= passengers_list.Count(); index++)
{
  if (passenger.Age <= findAge1 && passenger.Age >= findAge2)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Position: " + index + " Passagerare " + passenger.Name + " är " + passenger.Age + "år gammal");
  }
}
```

2. Use a Select method like Dmitry said with a ForEach method. The Select statement can give you an index that starts at 0 so you can add 1 to get the position.

```cs
passengers_list.Select((passenger, index) => (passenger, index+1))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(item =>
  {
    var (passenger, index) = item ;
    if(passenger.Age <= findAge1 && passenger.Age >= findAge2)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Position: " + index + " Passagerare " + passenger.Name + " är " + passenger.Age + "år gammal");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq* in order to query `passengers_list`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = passengers_list
  .Select((passenger, index) => (passenger, index))
  .Where(pair => pair.passenger.Age <= findAge1 && pair.passenger.Age >= findAge2)
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.index} name: {pair.passenger.Name} age: {pair.passenger.Age}");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```